# jquery script for autocomplete inside php script does not work inside <form> tags

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am doing an autocomplete for a input textbox in a php script.  This is the javascript.  Everything works fine...the search.php just fills in the div with options to select.  Here is the real issue.  When I put the input textbox inside  tags, then the div's that show the autocomplete options fail to render on the page.  I can put the divs anywhere on the page and it works as long as there is not a  anywhere on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".search").keyup(function()
{
var searchbox = $(this).val();
var dataString = 'searchword='+ searchbox;
if(clan_id=='')
{
}
else
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "search.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$("#display").html(html).show();
}
});
}return false;
});
});
jQuery(function($){
$("clan_id").Watermark("Search");
});
</script>
```

search.php is returning this code :

```
echo "<div class=\"display_box\" align=\"left\" onclick=\"document.getElementById  ('clan_id').value =' $final_clan_id '\">\n";
echo "<img src=\" $img \" style=\"width:25px; float:left; margin-right:6px\" />$final_clan_name  <br/></div>\n";
```

autocomplete works with this:

```
echo "<input type \"text\" id=\"clan_id\">\n";
```

autocomplete fails with this:

```
echo "<form name ='showClan' method='post' action='" .  htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "'>\n";
echo "<input type \"text\" id=\"clan_id\">\n";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Hold on a second.  I see "autocomplete works with this" but where is this?!?  Search.php is being returned by Ajax to another page...but where is the content of that page?  There's nowhere near enough context to help.

Answer (score 0):

In reviewing and testing out your code a couple things stand out:

1) Your search field doesn't have the "search" class that your jQuery function is looking for.

2) And your type attribute is missing the equals sign in both your examples.

```
<input class="search" type="text" id="clan_id">
```

And here's a working example with the search field and display div wrapped in a form:

http://jsfiddle.net/hansvedo/zhQse/